# Can not find a declaration for NSXMLElement while working with xmpp framework in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, sdk

I am trying to develop chatting application for iPhone. 
To achieve this, I've used xmpp framework, but when I try to integrate it with xcode project, I get an error like:

> can not find an interface declaration for NSXMLElement

When I see `NSXMLElement` document it is a class of mac os sdk, not iPhone. So how do I solve this problem ?

Comment: any other replacement for NSXMLElement ?
source: http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/wiki/iPhone

Comment: my goal is to develop chatting application in iphone. (Is there any other way apart from xmpp framework using which i can develop chatting application in iphone)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check out [KissXML](http://deusty.blogspot.com/2008/09/nsxml-on-iphone.html)